# Ramdisk size limit in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, memory, ramdisk

I tried this command to create a ramdisk

```
sudo hdik -nomount ram://4194304
```

but it failed with the message **hdik: attach failed: error 0x6e = 110**

It works only if I decrease the size to about 1 GB. Is there any ramdisk limit in OS X or did I miss something?

Using Mac OS X Mountain Lion with 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 6):

It seems there's some kind of limitation when using hdik. 
You can try using hdiutil to create the ramdisk.

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "ram disk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://4194304`
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Maybe one question more. Once the ram disk is created and populated with data, the diskimage-helper process in the Activity Monitor shows more or less the memory usage of ramdisk. Since I use ramdisk as temporary file location, the temporary files are regularly cleaned up. Why does the diskimage-helper however still show the maximal memory usage? Is there any way to "free" the memory hold by diskimage-helper without unmounting it?